Count how many employees are active for any week and how many were term as well for that week if any
I have a bigquery table like this:
Sample of the table I'm working with
What I need to do is to be able to tell by each week (week starting Sunday) how many active employees are and how many left if any
One thing to note is that both dates are in string format, so I have to cast them and when someone is still active the term_date will be null.
I've tried some different things including pivoting the data with might be the one way, but my issue with that is that since both dates are different for any particular employee I'm not sure how to create a "overall week"
I also tried this:
    SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(hire_date), WEEK, 'UTC') AS main_week,
  department,
  job_specialist,
  score,
  cat_1
  hire_date,
  term_date,
IF
  (TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(term_date), WEEK, 'UTC') = TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(Most_Recent_Hire_Date), WEEK, 'UTC'),1,0) AS term_number
FROM
  `course_dataset.employee_roster`
GROUP BY
  department,
  job_specialist,
  score,
  cat_1
  hire_date,
  term_date,
ORDER BY
  this_week ASC

My idea with this first was to use hire_date as my overall week, since there's never going to be a term_date before the hire_date. The second thing was to use term_number to be a column of ones and zeroes and then just get the sum by week, but the numbers I get don't match.
I just don't know how to get the logic of it to try something better as well

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. and  Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question both apply here. Why are the dates in string format? They're dates, and should be in the table that way. Using the wrong data type for your column means you have to keep fighting to find a way to do something that would be simple if you had just done things right in the first place.

This is a college assignment the data was given to me as is. I don't get why people need to post just to increase post count and not actually give any kind of help or guidance that can lead people to solve the issue.

This site has requirements for a reason, which is to make sure that sufficient details are here for future site users. The purpose of this site is not to help individual people with immediate problems, but to build a knowledge base for programmers. Your post is missing details, which I have asked you to provide properly. The fact it's your homework is irrelevant, except it brings up How to Ask (And Answer) Homework Questions? as well as the links I provided earlier. I'd also suggest you check your attitude - you're asking us to help you.

As far as my comment about dates, it's information that you should keep for the future. Your post failed to mention that it was homework, and not your data design. If you had done so, there would have been no need for my comment, would there?
